# Postgres join on Json Array with bigint column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to join a table containing json array data e.g: `'["1", "2", "3"]'`with a table having bigint column.
I was unable to find the solution

**category**

```
name       courseids(JSON Array)
name123    ["1", "2", "3"]
name321    ["4", "8", "10"]
```

**course**

```
id       name
1        coursename
2        coursename
3        coursename
```

Expect:

```
course_name    category_name
...........    .............
```

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: added expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your JSON array contains strings not numbers, you can join using the [contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) `?`  after converting `course.id` to a text value. The operator checks if the array contains the value on the right hand side.

```
select cat.name as category_name, co.name as course_name
from category cat
  join course co on cat.courseids ? co.id::text
order by cat.name
```

The `?` operator only works for `jsonb` columns. If your column is defined as one (which it should be), you need to cast that column as well:

```
join course co on cat.courseids::jsonb ? co.id::text
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d9279af41a3adab8338d4f24aea37de9)

Comment: a table containing **json array data** e.g: ``` '["1", "2", "3"]' ```

Comment: @M.WaseemUllahKhan: yes, that works with arrays as well (because the array values are stored as a string, not as a JSON number). See the online demo

Comment: i tried this it said ```ERROR:  operator does not exist: json ? text```
i also tried casting json::text still not worked
is there any use of @> operator?

Comment: @M.WaseemUllahKhan: you need `jsonb` not `json`. If your column isn't `jsonb` then you should convert it. You can workaround this in your case by using `on cat.courseids::jsonb ? co.id::text`

Comment: Thanks alot man <3 i was working on this for 3 hours. i casted it to ::jsonb and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try using `UNEST` in your array inside a subquery or [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html) and from there `JOIN` it with the table course, e.g.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE category (name TEXT, courseids JSONB);
INSERT INTO category VALUES ('name123','["1", "2", "3"]'),('name321','["4", "8", "10"]');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE course (id INT, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO course VALUES (1,'course1'),(2,'course2'),(3,'course3');

WITH j (name,courseid) AS (
  SELECT name,jsonb_array_elements(courseids)->>0
  FROM category cat
)
SELECT j.name AS course_name, c.name AS category_name FROM j
JOIN course c ON c.id::TEXT = j.courseid;

 course_name | category_name 
-------------+---------------
 name123     | course1
 name123     | course2
 name123     | course3
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3c91d89a96ee3a0d6c466dcfdadd82b8)

**Note**: The casting `c.id::TEXT` is necessary because the array `courseids` is a `TEXT` array and `id` at course is a `BIGINT`.

Comment: Thanks but courseids is a json array data

Comment: @M.WaseemUllahKhan well, you didn't originally post it in your question. see my edit and demo for json arrays.

Comment: can you check this i did some changes in table name it is giving null as courseid
```WITH j (name, courseid) AS (
  SELECT name,json_array_elements(cat.coursewares)->>0
  FROM KM_CATEGORY_MAST cat
)
SELECT j.name AS course_name, c.name AS category_name FROM j
JOIN KM_COURSE_MAST c ON c.id::TEXT = j.courseid;
```

Comment: does `SELECT name,json_array_elements(cat.coursewares)->>0 FROM KM_CATEGORY_MAST cat ` return any meaningful value?

Comment: i tried adding ```select * from j;``` after with clause and found out courseid was null

Comment: @M.WaseemUllahKhan so the jsonb array isn't being parsed at all. How does the jsonb column exactly look like?